# SQL Server 2019 Cannot Change Password for sa

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL server 2019and cannot change the password of my 'sa' login.

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245394/sql-server-2014-password-wont-change already and tried it, but it simply would not work.

I went to the login properties of sa, as below:
[image]

And changed the 'Password' and 'Confirm Password' fields, then clicked on 'OK'. But when I click back on the 'sa' properties, the original password reappears and remains un changed.

Note that in status, I have login enabled:
[image]

I have also tried running the following query to reset the 'sa' password:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;  
GO  
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = 'some123strong987password' ;  
GO
```

Still, it would not work. The password field simply goes back to the original password and remains unchanged.

I'm really clueless now as to what to do. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: **more clarification concerning what I did:**
Step 1:
Set password to 'sa', then click 'OK'
[image]

Step 2:
Right click on the SQL server itself, then click 'Restart'
[image]

Step 3:
Disconnect then reconnect to server
[image]

Note that the authentification I used is 'sa' for both login and password:
[image]

I then get the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since it's clear you don't know the actual `sa` password, you should follow the directions in [this Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)

FYI, there is no "default" password for SQL Server's sa account.  It gets setup during installation, *by you*.  If you didn't specify mixed mode authentication, then SQL Server is running in Windows Authentication mode, which means you cannot login using sa and a password.

Realize that when you look at the login properties in SSMS, the password is *never* actually shown.  Asterisks are displayed in the "Password" and "Confirm Password" text boxes but they bear no resemblance to the actual password stored in the system.  In fact, there is no password actually stored by SQL Server, the only thing stored by SQL Server is the hash of the password, i.e. a mathematical representation of the password which is compared with the same mathematical representation calculated when you enter the password at login.

The directions for resetting the SA password when you have lost the password consist of:

Perform these instructions while logged in to Windows as a member of the local administrators group.

1. From the Windows Start menu, right-click the icon for SQL Server Configuration Manager and choose Run as administrator to pass your administrator credentials to Configuration Manager.
2. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the left pane, select SQL Server Services. In the right-pane, find your instance of SQL Server. (The default instance of SQL Server includes (MSSQLSERVER) after the computer name. Named instances appear in upper case with the same name that they have in Registered Servers.) Right-click the instance of SQL Server, and then click Properties.
3. On the Startup Parameters tab, in the Specify a startup parameter box, type -m and then click Add. (That's a dash then lower case letter m.)
4. Click OK, and after the message to restart, right-click your server name, and then click Restart.
5. After SQL Server has restarted, your server will be in single-user mode. Make sure that SQL Server Agent is not running. If started, it will take your only connection.
6. From the Windows Start menu, right-click the icon for Management Studio and select Run as administrator. This will pass your administrator credentials to SSMS.

   - In some configurations, SSMS will attempt to make several connections. Multiple connections will fail because SQL Server is in single-user mode. Based on your scenario, perform one of the following actions.

   a. Connect with Object Explorer using Windows Authentication, which includes your Administrator credentials. Expand Security, expand Logins, and double-click your own login. On the Server Roles page, select sysadmin, and then click OK.

   b. Instead of connecting with Object Explorer, connect with a Query Window using Windows Authentication (which includes your Administrator credentials). (You can only connect this way if you did not connect with Object Explorer.) Execute code such as the following to add a new Windows Authentication login that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role. The following example adds a domain user named CONTOSO\PatK.

   ```
    CREATE LOGIN [CONTOSO\PatK] FROM WINDOWS;  
    ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [CONTOSO\PatK];
   ```

   c. If your SQL Server is running in mixed authentication mode, connect with a Query Window using Windows Authentication (which includes your Administrator credentials). Execute code such as the following to create a new SQL Server authentication login that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

   ```
    CREATE LOGIN TempLogin WITH PASSWORD = '************';  
    ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER TempLogin;
   ```

   d. If your SQL Server is running in mixed authentication mode and you want to reset the password of the sa account, connect with a Query Window using Windows Authentication (which includes your Administrator credentials). Change the password of the sa account with the following syntax.

   ```
    ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '************';
   ```
7. Close Management Studio.
8. These next few steps change SQL Server back to multi-user mode. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the left pane, select SQL Server Services.
9. In the right-pane, right-click the instance of SQL Server, and then click Properties.
10. On the Startup Parameters tab, in the Existing parameters box, select -m and then click Remove.
11. Right-click your server name, and then click Restart. Make sure to start SQL Server Agent again if you stopped it before starting SQL Server in single-user mode.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that implements Hannah Vernon's recommendation for creating a sysadmin Windows login when you don't have the `sa` password:

For a default instance:

```
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver 
sqlcmd -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

For a named instance:

```
net stop mssql$sqlexpress 
net start mssql$sqlexpress /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssql$sqlexpress
net start mssql$sqlexpress
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same problems as you did. I loved Hannah's explanation and directions but after I turned my server into a single-user mode on step 5 I took a slightly different approach:

###### 6) After turning the server into single-user mode, I created the user through Powershell instead of SSMS via the sqlcmd utility

PS > `sqlcmd -S [servername] -E -W`

###### 6b) I created a login:

```
> CREATE LOGIN [login_name] WITH PASSWORD='[password]';
> GO
```

###### 6c) I then gave the login name SYSADMIN privileges

```
> SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER [login_name],'SYSADMIN'; 
> GO
```

###### 7) I closed Powershell.

I then followed Hannahs steps 8 - 11. After Step 11 I was able to login to SSMS with the new user!

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOvbjo1tlYo)

Answer (score -4):

you can make a new windows user with administrative privilage , then run ssms and change the password on it , or make a new user in sql server .

Comment: Unfortunately unless a Windows admin already has a sysadmin-level login in SQL Server, this won't work.